# How can I add query parameters to a node.js/express.js res.redirect function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to use redirect users to a Google Authorization page in my app.  For my situation, I can't use any Google API modules.

I know I can format my `res.redirect()` function as such:

```
res.redirect('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth&client_id=690512789525-g8dbv0s1jo80u5hvevptqapeqokq7ees.apps.googleusercontent.com&hl=en&from_login=1&as=-6cc9a02870d13e22&authuser=0')
```

But I would prefer something cleaner, where I could keep my query parameters in an object. Something like:

```
res.redirect({
  uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth,
  scope: 'https://............etc',
  response_type: 'code',
  [...etc...]
})
```

With each of my query params as an attribute-value pair in my object.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

A think you need something like this `url.format(urlObj)`: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_format_urlobj